# SplitInstallStateUpdatedListener for SplitInstallManager is not working properly (App Bundle)

Tags: android, android-app-bundle

I am working on App bundle module download.

SplitInstallStateUpdatedListener for SplitInstallManager is not giving callback response every time, sometime it giving delayed response sometime NOT.
I have applied registerListener on activity start and unregisterListener while finishing the activity.

Comment: Is there a question? Or did you intend to a file bug instead? If you want help, you should consider pasting the code you're using so we can ensure it's not a bug in your code.

Comment: I am facing problem that I am not getting callback in expected time (sometime getting response after 3-5 minutes and sometime not getting even after very long time).
Code:
splitInstallStateUpdatedListener = state -> {
            System.out.println("State sessionID:" + state.sessionId() + " state.status():" + state.status());
        };

Comment: This is just the definition of the listener, where is it passed?